# formset_factory is located in formsets.py, so why call from django.forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

Why is `"from django.forms import formset_factory"` used to import the `"formset_factory" function` when the function is located in `django/forms/formsets.py`?

Wouldn't you have to `import from formsets.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A regular **package** is typically implemented as a directory containing an `__init__.py` file. When a regular package is imported, this `__init__.py` file is implicitly executed, and the **objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace**

If you check `forms.__init__.py` source code, you could find that for readability and consistency, Django has imported `Field`, `Widget`,`Formset` all into `__init__.py` to simplify the client code writing, thus you don't have to write `forms.fields.CharField`, `forms.widget.Input`, etc. These module-level objects are bound directly to the package namespace and ready for use

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError  # NOQA
from django.forms.boundfield import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.fields import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.forms import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.formsets import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.models import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.widgets import *  # NOQA
```